# How to catch any character (including \n) in Visual Studio Regex

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio, wildcard

**What I want to do**:

I want to reformat a bunch of similarly written HTML files in Visual Studio. The html parts may have a different number of lines, but I know that they start with a `<div id="some_id">` tag and there is no other `<div>` tag enclosed. So how would I write a regex that catches any number of lines in between?

**What I tried so far**:

I can't use the `.`, because it doesn't catch line breaks. But I also don't know how to tell Visual Studio to catch either `\n` or `.`. I know how to use sets (like `[a-z0-9]`) but as soon as you put a `.` into them it turns into a literal. So `<div id="some_id">[.\n]*?</div>` catches only divs which contain a bunch of dots and new lines

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Visual Studio Find and Replace feature, you may match any chars including line breaks by using a `[\s\S\r]` character class. For some reason, `[\s\S]` does not match the CR (carriage return) symbol.

Your `[.\n]` char class only matches a literal `.` or  a newline.

Thus, use

```
<div id="some_id">[\s\S\r]*?</div>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

`[.\n]` will not for some reason, I suspect that `[.]` matches dot, not any character.

`(.|\n)` can be used to match any character including linefeed.

If you need to pick it up for group replace, then add extra brackets over whole sentense.

For example:

Match string:
`Assert.ThrowsException<(.*)>\(((.|\n)*?),((.|\n)*?)\);`

with replacement pattern:
`Assert.Throws<$1>($2);`

Can convert Visual studio style exception to xUnit style exception.